# how to decrypt in SJCL using 256 bit key

Tags: javascript, sjcl

i am new in SJCL crypto library, i am doing the following for encrypting the plain text using 256 bit key in

```
var h = sjcl.codec.hex ;
salt = h.fromBits(sjcl.random.randomWords('10','0'));

var encryptedMessage = sjcl.encrypt(password,message,{count:2048,salt:salt,ks:256});
```

but i am unable to decrypt the same cipher , i want to know how to decrypt this cipher .

Comment: What is the logic behind using a salt for encryption?

Comment: i dont know i just found it on the forum.

Comment: By default, sjcl will add salt, initialisation vector etc and set the correct parameters. Its probably better to let it choose these values for you. The output is JSON which can then be fed directly back into the  decrypt function.

Answer (score 0):

well after so many hit and try i found this line working for me.

```
sjcl.decrypt(password,encMessage,{count:2048,ks:256});
```